# Winter Bash 2017 is missing from the archives

Tags: support, bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

If you go to [winterbash.stackexchange.com](https://winterbash.stackexchange.com) it will redirect you to [this page](https://contests.stackoverflow.com/).

Which has all the other previous Winter Bashes (and other promos ran over the years) with a couple of screen captures from them.

**However, Winter Bash 2017, is *not* there!**

[image: Images of previous years' winter bashes]

Yes, I know you can just see WB 2017 by going to https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com, but shouldn't it be in the archives as well?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a bug. Looks like they create archive post for Winter Bash event only when taking the site itself down, which might happen long time after the event is over.

For example, [back in May 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20170508025416/https://stackpromos.com), the archive site still did not have entry for Winter Bash 2016.